# Opencart 2.x add only single item in cart with any quantity

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart-module

i want customer only add single item in her cart with any number of quantity. if cart already have item it's should be remove and newly added item add to cart in Opencart 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open system/library/cart.php. You will find follwoing function.

```
public function add
```

You can run delete query at very fast in this function.

Comment: yes it's work used system/library/cart.php clear() function

Answer (score 0):

```
public function add($product_id, $quantity = 1, $option = array(), $recurring_id = 0) { 
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "cart");
            $this->db->query("INSERT " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', recurring_id = '" . (int)$recurring_id . "', `option` = '" . $this->db->escape(json_encode($option)) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$quantity . "', date_added = NOW()");

    }
```

This is complete function.